# How to access an attribute of an object?

Tags: c#, attributes

I tried to write my own code to learn basics of OOP. I wanted to see the attribute Thickness of the cookie object to be printed, but it doesn’t print anything. Could you please explain in simple words what’s wrong? And also could you suggest what more I can do to exercise with this code? I want to make a subclass later and use ‘base’ kewyord, but I got stuck here. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    }
}

class Cookie
{
    public readonly double Width;
    public readonly double Thickness;

    public Cookie(double width, double thickness)
    {
        Width = width;
        Thickness = thickness;
    }
}

class AnAttempt
{
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(3.2, 1.5);
    public double AMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cookie.Thickness);
        return (cookie.Thickness);
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

Comment: Empty `Main()` => Your Program does nothing.

Comment: The `Main()` method is what gets called when this program runs, as it is empty then nothing happens.I assume you want to call `AMethod();` inside main.

Comment: In `AMethod` , `Console.ReadLine` is unreachable because you return before.

Comment: *what more I can do...* Buy a book.  There is a limit to how much you can learn by stumbling into some code that works

Comment: As pointed out by Fildor, don't 'forget' the Main() method next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Main Method is empty, so your program does nothing.

To get it to run your code (at least what I guess you want it to run) do this:

```
static void Main()
    {
        AnAttempt local = new AnAttempt(); // creates a new instance of AnAttempt class 
        local.AMethod();  // and calls AMethod on it.
    }
```

You will have unreachable code, though:

```
public double AMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cookie.Thickness);
        return (cookie.Thickness); // < you return here ...
        Console.ReadLine();        // so this line will never be executed.
    }
```

For exercises, I would say find a good beginners' book or look out for some Online-Course or even YT-Videos. Asking on SO will not get you far, because that's not what this site is for.

Comment: For beginners I would advice not instancing and calling the instanced methods in the same line, could potentially confuse them.